# Finding first and last element of the list using recursive

Tags: algorithm, scala, list, recursion, functional-programming

I am trying to write recursive function in Scala returning first and last element of the list (pair). I'd like to only use `.head` and `.tail` without `match` using simple (not tail) recursive (without defining additional function). Is it possible?

Last element I can find using this code:

```
def foo(x: List[Int]): (Int) = {
    if (x.tail.isEmpty) (x.head)
    else foo(x.tail)
}
```

I'd like to return pair with first and last element `(Int, Int)`. Parameter is `(x: List[Int])`. It is easy if I pass `head` as parameter but is it possible without doing it?

Comment: use tail recursion instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a inner, recursive function for the tail, and have an outer function for the head.

However - whether this is still in the spirit of the exercise, is another question.

Here is a very inefficient solution:

```
def firstAndLast (list: List[Int]): (Int, Int) = {
  if (list.isEmpty) (0, 0) 
  else if (list.size == 1) (list.head, list.head) 
  else if (list.size == 2)
     (list.head, list.tail.head)
  else
    firstAndLast (list.head :: list.tail.tail)
}
```

It carries the head not as a separate parameter, but by reappending it at head of the rest of rest of the list, if it is longer than 2.

For a meaningful return for the empty case, I had no good idea. Return Option of tuple in general would be a way.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach

```
 def headTail(l:List[Int]) : (Int, Int) = {
  if(l.isEmpty) (-1, -1)
  else if(l.tail == List())  (l.head, -1)
  else if(l.tail.tail.isEmpty)  (l.head, l.tail.head)
  else headTail(l.head :: l.tail.tail) //eliminates second element for every iteration
}
```